# How to add events to the individual sections(arcs) of a pie chart created out of d3.js?

Tags: charts, event-handling, d3.js, pie-chart

> This is a basic code to create a pie chart for protocol distribution. In my .csv file, I have two columns viz., protocol name and the percentage.I want to add events on individual arcs.  For example, when i click only on the arc containing TCP stats, it should lead to another page. Please help how can i do this. I was able to add click event for the pie chart as whole.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.count; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.csv("flow_count.csv", function(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.count = +d.count;
  });

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.proto); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.proto; });
       g.on( "click", function(d,i) {
        window.location.href='index.html';
})

});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code? It looks like this will draw a bar chart instead of a pie chart, as you say in the description.

Comment: sorry, by mistake i appended bar chart's code. I have edited it now. And have added the function that on click leads to another page. But still want to figure out how to add events on a single arc and not on the pie as a whole

Comment: It looks like the g.on("clicK", ... ) is linked to individual arcs, but they are all directing to the same page (index.html). You need to rewrite the function itself so that the redirect varies based on d or i.

Answer (score 3):

Within the "svg.selectAll(".bar") you could add an on click line:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .on("click", function(d) {
          // code you want executed on the click event 
      });
```